# .GraphQL missing type after importing another .graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Hello i am learning GraphQL. during learning i found out that instead creating Schema in hardcode .js file it is good idea to use .graphql file directory for writing fields etc.

I installed `babel-plugin-import-graphql` for importing other .graphql file but when ever i run server i always receive `missing type Otp`

.rootGraphql

```
#import Otp from "ac.graphql"

type Query {
    Otp: Otp
}
```

.ac.graphql

```
type Otp {
    mobilenumber(no: String!): String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're pointing to the right file path for `ac.graphql`, try the following:

`type Query {
    otp: Otp
}`

which uses lower-case for attribute names, and upper-case for the attribute *type*.

You can't use upper-case `Otp` as attribute name because it would conflict with the imported `Otp` *type*.

(For other types you may use upper-case attribute names, but generally it's good practice to uppercase your types/classes and lowercase all instantiations.)